# How to fetch data from server (PHP) using RPC in json format in Android

Tags: android, json, rpc

I am new in Android. I am trying to make an `RPC` to fetch data from `PHP` and get in `JSON` format. Everything goes fine but I am not getting any data as response. Bellow is my android code

### Android Code

```
try{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject(); 
    jsonRequest.put("id", 0); 
    jsonRequest.put("method", "getData"); 


    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonRequest.toString()); 
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://121.247.130.30:8080/test/TestJava.php");
    request.setEntity(entity); 
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 
    String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.e("Class====","Error:"+temp);
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("Class====","Error:"+e.getMessage());
   }
```

### PHP Code

```
<?php
class TestJava
{
public function getData()  
{  
   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   echo json_encode($arr);
} 
}
?>
```

Please let me know if anything I did here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misused entity element. Check what I have in my code:

```
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK ){

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    response.getEntity().consumeContent();
    out.close();
    return out.toString();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have written your code snippet and now got 200 response code, but the problem is that BytearrayOutputStream object contains blank data. And object's ('out' here) bugffer is like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. and Finally I am receiving this error every time-java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed. Where I have done wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the return. I cant see what you did wrong. In my code, this is right after the httpclient.execute(...

Answer (score 0):

I am a little surprised how you could retrieve any information from this php script. This script doesnt output anything. Try it like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The second "strange" thing is your way of receiving data in your app. You should read a input stream instead of writing into a output stream... Or did I completely miss something?!

Comment: yes you right Marco. My problem was not with the php script, actually my problem is that I am looking for a solution where I will have one class that will make a connection bridge to a php class, and using that connection I can access that class's method/procedure where I can manage result handler or fault handler.